# After I submit form with uploading photos, there are nothing to save on Django database

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I met a problem.

When I choose a photo as a profile_pic on the registration page,

it saves any information without a photo.

But I can't find out why it didn't work.

[image]

There is nothing in the Profile pic after submitting.

[image]

setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for learning_templates project.
 
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.7.
 
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/
 
For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
 
from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/
 
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'pgmh_#pcqd(3sf(a3oj#^vyv4l-#p6g=n-=^!z)0d@!k)!_ear'
 
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
 
 
# Application definition
 
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'basic_app',
]
 
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
 
ROOT_URLCONF = 'learning_templates.urls'
 
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
 
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'learning_templates.wsgi.application'
 
 
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases
 
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
 
 
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
PASSWORD_HASHERS=[
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
]
 
 
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS':{'min_length':9}
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
 
 
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/
 
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
 
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
 
USE_I18N = True
 
USE_L10N = True
 
USE_TZ = True
 
 
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[STATIC_DIR,]
 
#MEDIA
MEDIA_ROOT=MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
 
LOGIN_URL='basic_app/user_login'
```

in views.py: register

```
def register(request):
    
    registered= False
    logging.error(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       user_form= UserForm(data=request.POST)
       profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm(request.POST)
       logging.error(user_form) 
       if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
           user=user_form.save()
           
           user.set_password(user.password)
           user.save()
 
           profile=profile_form.save(commit=False)
           profile.user=user
 
           if 'profile_pics' in request.FILES:
               profile.profile_pic=request.FILES['profile_pics']
 
           profile.save()
           
           registered=True
       else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
 
    else:
        user_form=UserForm()
        profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm()
    
    return render(request,'basic_app/registeration.html',
    {'user_form':user_form,
    'profile_form':profile_form,
    'registered':registered})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 
# Create your models here.
 
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # additional
    portfolio_site=models.URLField(blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profile_pics', blank = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model=UserProfileInfo
        fields=('portfolio_site','profile_pic')
```

registeration.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "basic_app/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
  {% block body_block %}
  {{registered }}
    <div class=jumbotron>
      <h1>Test Register</h1>
      {% if registered %}
      <h1>Thank you for Register</h1> 
      {% else %}
      <h1>Register Here</h1>
      <h3>
          <h1>Fill out the form</h1>
          <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ user_form.as_p}}
              {{ profile_form.as_p }}
              <input type="submit" name="" value="Register">
          </form>
      </h3>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

[image]

And I have made sure that the profile_pics folder has nothing.

I don't know where I am wrong or what I miss but anything without a photo has saved.

If anything misses, please tell me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think that you don't need to check for request.FILES. maybe this is the problem

Comment: @D4NieLDev I removed the checking request.FILES but it still failed. It's so wierd.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the uploaded images is in your media/profile_pics folder.
Since you are viewing the data uploaded using the django admin panel ,it does not shows the actual image it will show the image name.

Try to display the image in a template by passing the user content in the context section while sending the rendering the template.

Comment: No. It doesn't exist in the media/profile folder.
And in the admin panel, it doesn't display the name.
Neither image nor name of image display there.
I still don't know how to solve it.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/ <br>